# Crystal reports not displaying bottom of Worksheet object

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report that I inserted a worksheet object into to keep formatting easier. Problem is when I export to pdf on another server the part near the bottom of the page of this object disappears, still keeps its outer borders but all the inner ones vanish. Made sure both environments had the same version of crystal installed and have tried tweaking some things in the section expert.

[image: PDF Printout]

[image: Report File]

Comment: Try pushing the bottom part up higher and see if the issue still occurs.  Also make sure everything under 'Page Setup' is as required.

Comment: Did that. The only thing that does seem to work is trying to shrink down everything because it doesn't seem to draw anything for the last quarter of the page.